# Rotating a triangle around its axis

Tags: java, swing

I have got a circle and a triangle inside. I need this figure to rotate around its axis and each time it rotates on a certain angle, it should be painted, overall to get something kind of 'ornament'(on the screen below). I've been trying with `Graphics2D`, but it went bad. How can I do that?

Code:

```
import org.omg.CORBA.TIMEOUT;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.AffineTransform;

public class Main extends JPanel {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Laboratorna 1");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(new Main());
        frame.setSize(1200, 800);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        int num_2 = 8;
        int bigOval_h = 300, bigOval_w = 300;

        g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        g.drawOval(0+500, 0, bigOval_h, bigOval_w);
        g.drawLine(150+500, 0, 20+500, 225);
        g.drawLine(150+500, 0, 280+500, 225);
        g.drawLine(20+500, 225,280+500, 225);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);

    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Sounds like a maths problem. But I'm unclear what you're asking. What is the exact problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: "it went bad" isn't a good enough explanation. Please read [ask] and tell us in what way "it went bad" (what you did, what you expected and what you got instead).

Comment: usually this is a linear algebra problem where you rotate the x,y coordinates of the vertices of the triangle..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to perform an affine transform for each angle. In addition you have to define the pivot point for each transform which equals the center of the circle. The following modifications of the paintComponent-method should possibly do the job.

```
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){

       int num_2 = 8;
       int bigOval_h = 300, bigOval_w = 300;

       g.setColor(Color.BLUE);
       g.drawOval(0 + 500, 0, bigOval_h, bigOval_w);
       // REMOVE -------------------------------------------
       // g.drawLine(150+500, 0, 20+500, 225);
       // g.drawLine(150+500, 0, 280+500, 225);
       // g.drawLine(20+500, 225,280+500, 225);
       // REMOVE -------------------------------------------
       g.setColor(Color.RED);

       // ADD -------------------------------------------------------------------
       // Create, transform and draw the lines
       Line2D lin1 = new Line2D.Float(150f + 500f, 0f, 20f + 500f, 225f);
       Line2D lin2 = new Line2D.Float(150f + 500f, 0f, 280f + 500f, 225f);
       Line2D lin3 = new Line2D.Float(20f + 500f, 225f, 280f + 500f, 225f);
       double pivotX = 500.0 + bigOval_w / 2.0; // center of the circle (x)
       double pivotY = 0.0 + bigOval_h / 2.0;   // center of the circle (y)
       for (int i = 0; i < num_2; i++) {
          AffineTransform affineTransform = AffineTransform.getRotateInstance(Math.toRadians(360.0 / num_2 * i), pivotX, pivotY);
          ((Graphics2D)g).draw(affineTransform.createTransformedShape(lin1));
          ((Graphics2D)g).draw(affineTransform.createTransformedShape(lin2));
          ((Graphics2D)g).draw(affineTransform.createTransformedShape(lin3));
       }
       // ADD -------------------------------------------------------------------
   }
```

The output is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One way to define a polygon is radius, rotation, and number of sides. A triangle is a 3 sided polygon. So a triangle class can simply save radius and rotation and then compute the three vertices of the polygon for drawing around a center point.

```
public class Triangle {
    private final int radius;
    private final double rotation;

    public Triangle(int radius, double rotation) {
        this.radius = radius;
        this.rotation = rotation;
    }

    public void paintComponent(Graphics2D g, Point center) {    
        int[] xVertices = new int[3];
        int[] yVertices = new int[3];

        xVertices[0] = (int) (center.getX() - (Math.cos(rotation) * radius));
        yVertices[0] = (int) (center.getY() - (Math.sin(rotation) * radius));
        xVertices[1] = (int) (center.getX() - (Math.cos(Math.PI * 0.66667 + rotation) * radius));
        yVertices[1] = (int) (center.getY() - (Math.sin(Math.PI * 0.66667 + rotation) * radius));
        xVertices[2] = (int) (center.getX() - (Math.cos(Math.PI * 1.33333 + rotation) * radius));
        yVertices[2] = (int) (center.getY() - (Math.sin(Math.PI * 1.33333 + rotation) * radius));

        Polygon polygon = new Polygon(xVertices, yVertices, 3);
        g.setColor(Color.RED);
        g.drawPolygon(polygon);
    }
}
```

This would give two triangles rotated PI radians.

```
Triangle t = new Triangle(100, 0.0);
t.paintComponent((Graphics2D)g, new Point(250,250));
Triangle t2 = new Triangle(100, Math.PI);
t2.paintComponent((Graphics2D)g, new Point(250,250));
```

[image]